# Add options to a select from an array with jQuery using Spring tags

Tags: jquery, json, spring-mvc

When I use Spring tags, auto population of select box doesnt work.

Below solution works,

```
    <html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
      <select id="articleLocation">
      </select>
    </body>
    </html>

    /*javascript*/
    var jsonList = {"Table" : [{"stateid" : "2","statename" : "Tamilnadu"},
                {"stateid" : "3","statename" : "Karnataka"},
                {"stateid" : "4","statename" : "Andaman and Nicobar"},
                 {"stateid" : "5","statename" : "Andhra Pradesh"},
                 {"stateid" : "6","statename" : "Arunachal Pradesh"}]}

    $(document).ready(function(){
      var listItems= "";
      for (var i = 0; i < jsonList.Table.length; i++){
        listItems+= "<option value='" + jsonList.Table[i].stateid + "'>" + jsonList.Table[i].statename + "</option>";
      }
      $("#articleLocation").html(listItems);
    });
```

Below solution (using Spring tags) doesnt work. Error message is "The 'option' tag can only be used inside a valid 'select' tag."

```
    <html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
      <form:select path="articleLocation">                                                 
      </form:select>
    </body>
    </html>

    /*javascript*/
    var jsonList = {"Table" : [{"stateid" : "2","statename" : "Tamilnadu"},
                {"stateid" : "3","statename" : "Karnataka"},
                {"stateid" : "4","statename" : "Andaman and Nicobar"},
                 {"stateid" : "5","statename" : "Andhra Pradesh"},
                 {"stateid" : "6","statename" : "Arunachal Pradesh"}]}

    var listItems= "";
    for (var i = 0; i < jsonList.Table.length; i++){
      listItems+= "<form:option value='" + jsonList.Table[i].stateid + "' label='" + jsonList.Table[i].statename + "'/>";
    }
    $("#articleLocation").appendTo(listItems);
```

Comment: That's not JSTL. I edited and fixed the question. You shouldn't overgeneralize 3rd party taglibraries as JSTL. To learn what JSTL really is, head to our JSTL wiki page: http://stackoverflow.com/tags/jstl/info

Comment: You're mixing server side and client side. See what the `<form:option>` renders as a HTML source code, and mimic it using classic HTML.

Comment: thanks for correcting me BalusC. I did go through the link you provided. @sp00m - I have used the classic HTML to fix the issue before posting this question but thought of asking the question to know why it is not working with spring tags. Thanks for your comments!